# Reason for the lack of addMinutes in QDateTime class

Tags: c++, qt, sdk, qt4, qt5

I was looking for the `addMinutes` method in the `QDateTime` class, but unfortunately there is no such thing as adding minutes to a datetime object and I had to use `addSecs` method instead. I took a look at the header file of the `QDateTime` class, and noticed that there are `add-times` methods for quite all time resolutions except the `addMinutes`:

```
...
 QDateTime addDays(int days) const;
 QDateTime addMonths(int months) const;
 QDateTime addYears(int years) const;
 QDateTime addSecs(int secs) const;
 QDateTime addMSecs(qint64 msecs) const
...
```

This sounds quite odd to me, what is the reason for such ommision?

Comment: add(M)Secs() is coming from QTime, the rest from QDate. I think one is expected to do addSecs(60) to add a minute or addSecs(3600) to add an hour.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that adding a minute is quite difficult: it could mean adding 60 seconds or 61 seconds (leap second). As the moments, where a minute has 61 seconds are not known far in advance, the Qt designers leave that up to you.

Comment: In `.Net Framework` for example, the `DateTime` class has `addMinutes` method along with other **add-time-reslutions**, but these methods take a `double` argument as input.

Answer (score 0):

`addMins(minutes)` would be equivalent to `addSecs(minutes * 60)`, so why bother to provide another convenience method for such a simple calculation? I think I'd have decided similarly if the API design were mine. Adding days, months, years to a date demands more complex calculations, and one can't easily be replaced by the other. As QDateTime is just a wrapper around QDate + QTime I think this should explain the interface.